# CMake cross compilation for ARM Cortex-M on windows error linking

Tags: cmake, arm, cross-compiling, mingw-w64

I want to develop embedded systems in Clion, so I am porting an existing Makefile to CMake. I am using MinGW generator.
The code compiles correctly (the right compiler, the right flags) but the linking step fails, claiming ld cannot accept --major-image-version as an argument. This is a build log after everything else has been compiled and just the linking step failing:

```
    [  3%] Linking C executable Glamdring.elf.exe
A:\CLion_2020.1.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\Glamdring.elf.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
A:\CLion_2020.1.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe -E remove -f CMakeFiles\Glamdring.elf.dir/objects.a
arm-none-eabi-ar cr CMakeFiles\Glamdring.elf.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\Glamdring.elf.dir\objects1.rsp
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -g   -Wl,-Map=C:/Users/migue/proyectos/Glamdring/STM32G070/cmake-build-debug/Glamdring.map -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\Glamdring.elf.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o Glamdring.elf.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libGlamdring.elf.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\Glamdring.elf.dir\linklibs.rsp
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/8 2019-q3-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: unrecognized option '--major-image-version'
c:/program files (x86)/gnu tools arm embedded/8 2019-q3-update/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/8.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: use the --help option for usage information
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Glamdring.elf.dir\build.make:541: Glamdring.elf.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/migue/proyectos/Glamdring/STM32G070/cmake-build-debug'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:75: CMakeFiles/Glamdring.elf.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/migue/proyectos/Glamdring/STM32G070/cmake-build-debug'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:83: all] Error 2
```

The contents of the auto-generated **link.txt** the build aludes to are:

```
A:\CLion_2020.1.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe -E remove -f CMakeFiles\Glamdring.elf.dir/objects.a
arm-none-eabi-ar cr CMakeFiles\Glamdring.elf.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\Glamdring.elf.dir\objects1.rsp
arm-none-eabi-gcc -Wall -mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP -g   -Wl,-Map=C:/Users/migue/proyectos/Glamdring/STM32G070/cmake-build-debug/Glamdring.map -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\Glamdring.elf.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o Glamdring.elf.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libGlamdring.elf.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 @CMakeFiles\Glamdring.elf.dir\linklibs.rsp
```

There one can see the aforementioned --major-image-version being passed as an argument.
The CMakeLists.txt file I am using is this:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project (Glamdring)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 1)

enable_language(C ASM)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

##############################################################
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS 1)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER arm-none-eabi-g++)
set(CMAKE_AS arm-none-eabi-as)
set(CMAKE_AR arm-none-eabi-ar)
set(CMAKE_OBJCOPY arm-none-eabi-objcopy)
set(CMAKE_OBJDUMP arm-none-eabi-objdump)
set(CMAKE_SIZE arm-none-eabi-size)
set(CMAKE_GDB arm-none-eabi-gdb)
#
set(CMAKE_ADDR2LINE arm-none-eabi-addr2line)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER  arm-none-eabi-gcc)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER_AR  arm-none-eabi-gcc-ar)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER_RANLIB   arm-none-eabi-gcc-ranlib)
##############################################################

set(M0 "-mcpu=cortex-m0plus -mthumb")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Wall ${M0} -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections -gdwarf-2 -MMD -MP")

set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER ${CMAKE_C_COMPILER})
set(CMAKE_ASM_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -x assembler-with-cpp")
##############################################################

set(ldscript "STM32G070RBTx_FLASH.ld")
set(LINKER_SCRIPT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/${ldscript})
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_INIT "-Wl,-gc-sections,--print-memory-usage --specs=nosys.specs -T $${LINKER_SCRIPT}")
#target_link_options(glam PUBLIC SHELL:${M0} -specs=nano.specs -T../STM32G070RBTx_FLASH.ld -Wl,-Map=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections)
#target_link_libraries(glam c m nosys)

set(target ${PROJECT_NAME}.elf)

add_executable(${target}
        Src/dma.c
        Src/gpio.c Src/usart.c
        Src/main.c
        Src/stm32g0xx_hal_msp.c
        Src/stm32g0xx_hal_timebase_tim.c
        Src/stm32g0xx_it.c
        Src/system_stm32g0xx.c
        Src/tim.c
        Src/adc.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_adc.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_adc_ex.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_gpio.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_exti.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_tim.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_tim_ex.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_uart.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_uart_ex.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_rcc.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_rcc_ex.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_ll_rcc.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_flash.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_flash_ex.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_dma.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_dma_ex.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_pwr.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_pwr_ex.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_cortex.c
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal.c
        startup_stm32g070xx.s
        ${LINKER_SCRIPT} )

set_target_properties(${target} PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME ${target})
target_include_directories(${target} PUBLIC
        Inc
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc
        Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy
        Drivers/CMSIS/Include
        Drivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32G0xx/Include
        )

target_compile_definitions(${target} PUBLIC USE_HAL_DRIVER STM32G070xx)

set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} -Wl,-Map=${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.map")

set(HEX_FILE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.hex)
set(BIN_FILE ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/${PROJECT_NAME}.bin)

add_custom_command(TARGET ${target} POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${OBJCOPY} -Oihex $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}.elf> ${HEX_FILE}
        COMMAND ${OBJCOPY} -Obinary $<TARGET_FILE:${PROJECT_NAME}.elf> ${BIN_FILE}
        COMMENT "Generando ${HEX_FILE}
        Generando ${BIN_FILE}"
        )
```

And this is the Makefile I am trying to port from:

```
TARGET = STM32G070


######################################
# building variables
######################################
# debug build?
DEBUG = 1
# optimization
OPT = -Og -std=c99


#######################################
# paths
#######################################
# Build path
BUILD_DIR = build

######################################
# source
######################################
# C sources
C_SOURCES =  \
Src/dma.c \
Src/gpio.c \
Src/usart.c \
Src/main.c \
Src/stm32g0xx_hal_msp.c \
Src/stm32g0xx_hal_timebase_tim.c \
Src/stm32g0xx_it.c \
Src/system_stm32g0xx.c \
Src/tim.c \
Src/adc.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_gpio.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_adc.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_adc_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_tim.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_tim_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_uart.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_uart_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_rcc.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_rcc_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_ll_rcc.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_flash.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_flash_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_dma.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_dma_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_pwr.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_pwr_ex.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_cortex.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal.c \
Drivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32g0xx_hal_exti.c
#Src/app_freertos.c \
#Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/CMSIS_RTOS/cmsis_os.c \
#Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/tasks.c \
#Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/queue.c \
#Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/timers.c \
#Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/list.c \
#Middlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/RVDS/ARM_CM0/port.c

# ASM sources
ASM_SOURCES =  \
startup_stm32g070xx.s


#######################################
# binaries
#######################################
PREFIX = arm-none-eabi-
# The gcc compiler bin path can be either defined in make command via GCC_PATH variable (> make GCC_PATH=xxx)
# either it can be added to the PATH environment variable.
ifdef GCC_PATH
CC = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(GCC_PATH)/$(PREFIX)size
else
CC = $(PREFIX)gcc
AS = $(PREFIX)gcc -x assembler-with-cpp
CP = $(PREFIX)objcopy
SZ = $(PREFIX)size
endif
HEX = $(CP) -O ihex
BIN = $(CP) -O binary -S

#######################################
# CFLAGS
#######################################
# cpu
CPU = -mcpu=cortex-m0plus

# fpu
# NONE for Cortex-M0/M0+/M3

# float-abi


# mcu
MCU = $(CPU) -mthumb $(FPU) $(FLOAT-ABI)

# macros for gcc
# AS defines
AS_DEFS = 

# C defines
C_DEFS =  \
-DUSE_HAL_DRIVER \
-DSTM32G070xx


# AS includes
AS_INCLUDES = 

# C includes
C_INCLUDES =  \
-IInc \
-IDrivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc \
-IDrivers/STM32G0xx_HAL_Driver/Inc/Legacy \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Device/ST/STM32G0xx/Include \
-IDrivers/CMSIS/Include
#-IMiddlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/include \
#-IMiddlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/portable/RVDS/ARM_CM0 \
#-IMiddlewares/Third_Party/FreeRTOS/Source/CMSIS_RTOS


# compile gcc flags
ASFLAGS = $(MCU) $(AS_DEFS) $(AS_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

CFLAGS = $(MCU) $(C_DEFS) $(C_INCLUDES) $(OPT) -Wall -fdata-sections -ffunction-sections

ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
CFLAGS += -g -gdwarf-2
endif


# Generate dependency information
CFLAGS += -MMD -MP -MF"$(@:%.o=%.d)"


#######################################
# LDFLAGS
#######################################
# link script
LDSCRIPT = STM32G070RBTx_FLASH.ld

# libraries
LIBS = -lc -lm -lnosys 
LIBDIR = 
LDFLAGS = $(MCU) -specs=nano.specs -T$(LDSCRIPT) $(LIBDIR) $(LIBS) -Wl,-Map=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).map,--cref -Wl,--gc-sections

# default action: build all
all: $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).hex $(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).bin


#######################################
# build the application
#######################################
# list of objects
OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(C_SOURCES:.c=.o)))
vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(C_SOURCES)))
# list of ASM program objects
OBJECTS += $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/,$(notdir $(ASM_SOURCES:.s=.o)))
vpath %.s $(sort $(dir $(ASM_SOURCES)))

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.c Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR) 
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) -Wa,-a,-ad,-alms=$(BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(<:.c=.lst)) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.s Makefile | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(AS) -c $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET).elf: $(OBJECTS) Makefile
    $(CC) $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@
    $(SZ) $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.hex: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(HEX) $< $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.bin: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.elf | $(BUILD_DIR)
    $(BIN) $< $@    

$(BUILD_DIR):
    mkdir $@        

#######################################
# clean up
#######################################
clean:
    del /f /q $(BUILD_DIR)
#   -rm -fR $(BUILD_DIR)

#######################################
# dependencies
#######################################
-include $(wildcard $(BUILD_DIR)/*.d)
```

I think this linking error is a symptom of a bigger error in the design of my CMake script. Maybe my local MinGW toolchain is being mixed with the embedded toolchain, since when configuring & generating the former is found, but when I compile with VERBOSE=1 I can see the right arm-none-eabi-gcc is being used. Also I notice that **my output file persistently has the .exe extension**, when I actually want to produce a .elf. I'm guessing the "add_executable" command could be substituded for something else? Overall I know something is missing at the linking step. I searched for the ld command options, and noticed the option exists under x86 options - so I suspect my program is trying to be linked as an x86 executable, and not an .elf.

I've been with this problem for 3 days, and I have googled similar questions/answers but cannot make this work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: CMake has a nice description of cross-compiling and toolchains: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html. Have you read it? Just follow this description, and place all compiler/linker settings into the separate **toolchain file**.